# How to make a readable return of data

Tags: c++, qt

I read this article http://www.slideshare.net/redigon/refactoring-1658371 
 on page 53 it states that "You have a method that returns a value but also changes the state of the object. create two methods,one for the query and one for the modification.

But what if on the query I need the values of more than 1 field.

For example:

```
QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database("MAIN"));
QString command = "SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5 FROM TABLE";
query.exec( command );
```

This is the method I know but I really feel that this is not that readable

```
QString values;
columnDelimiter = "[!@#]";
rowDelimiter = "[$%^]";
while( query.next )
{
    values += query.value(0).toString() + columnDelimiter;
    values += query.value(1).toString() + columnDelimiter;
    values += query.value(2).toString() + columnDelimiter;
    values += query.value(3).toString() + columnDelimiter;
    values += rowDelimiter;
}
```

And I will retrive it like this.

```
QStringList rowValues, columnValues;

rowValues = values.split(rowDelimiter);

int rowCtr =0;

while( rowCtr < rowValues.count() )
{
    columnValues.clear();
    // Here i got the fields I need
    columnValues = rowValues.at( rowCtr ).split( columnDelimiter );
    // I will put the modification on variables here

    rowCtr++;

}
```

EDIT: Is there a more readable way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Is there a more readable way of doing this kind of procedure?

Comment: Use a for loop within your while loop?

Comment: You could create a `struct MyRow { QString fieldA, fieldB, fieldC }`. In your first `while(...)` you'll cumulate a `QList<MyRow> values`

Comment: Please post the complete codes so that I can understand. Thanks.

Comment: No. You've shown no effort to even understand what @taoufik or I have suggested.

Comment: ok Ill try, it means that the MyRow is the enum function at the header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Is there a more readable way of doing this?"* is a subjective question. I'm not sure whether your question will last long on SO, as SO prefers factual problems and solutions.

What *I personally* think will make your code more readable, would be:

- Use a custom made data structure for your data set. Strings are not the right data structures for tabulated data. Lists of custom made structs are better.

Example:

```
// data structure for a single row
struct MyRow {
    QString a, b, c;
}

...

QList<MyRow> myDataSet;
while( query.next )
{
    MyRow currentRow;
    // fill with data
    currentRow.a = query.value(0).toString();
    currentRow.b = query.value(1).toString();
    ...

    myDataSet.append(currentRow);
}
```

- I doubt all your data is text. Some is probably numbers. Never store numbers as strings. That's inefficient.
- You first read all data into a data structure, and then read the data structure to process it. Why don't you combine the two? I.e. process while reading the data, in the same `while(...)`
- In your comment, you're confused by the difference between an `enum` and `struct`. I suggest, stop doing complex database and QT stuff. Grab a basic C++ book and try to understand C++ first.